Is there a quick way to determine which release has a specific commit listed on an issue page?
When a Drupal.org issue gets committed, the issue page has a message like "Author committed hash on 11.x".  Is there a quick way to determine which stable release includes that commit?
For example, for this issue and comment, I can click the hash and check "Branches containing commit" to confirm it was on 11.x, but I want to know which stable release (or upcoming release) has the commit.
The Drupal release notes include all the issues that were part of the relevant release, but I don't see any way to search them for a specific issue.
How can I determine which release has a commit that I found on an issue page?

Git describe supports this. Here is an example:
$ git describe --all d38aac15
tags/11.0.0-alpha1-411-gd38aac1555

The commit you referenced released in Drupal version 11.0.0-alpha1.
